# Shell script to find the date 12 working days(ignoring holidays) from today

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having a little trouble trying to write a bash script that would find the date 12 working days later than the current day (ignoring holidays as that would complicate things quite a fair bit). A working day in this case would be Mon-Friday.

I'm not even really sure where to start with this! Any starting pointers would be great :)

Comment: In Perl you can use eg. Date::Holidays and DateTime, Time::Local, Time::Piece of similar modules. Google those :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume with workday you mean a day from Monday to Friday (even if Saturday might officially be a workday as well).

Sometimes twelve working days in the future is after three weekends, sometimes after two weekends.  So we have to find out whether we are on a Thursday/Friday or on Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday or on Saturday/Sunday.  It turns out that Sunday is the same case as Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday, so we end up using this:

```
weekday=$(date +%w)  # 0 is Sunday, 6 is Saturday

if [ $weekday -lt 4 ]  # Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday
then
  offset=16
elif [ $weekday -lt 6 ]  # Thursday/Friday
then
  offset=18
else  # Saturday
then
  offset=17
fi

date -d "today + $offset days"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 16 days (12 working days = 5 + 5 + 2, so in general days it is 7 + 7 + 2). For Thursdays and Fridays, you have to add two more days to skip weekends.

```
 #! /bin/bash

increment=16
day=$(date +%w)
[[ $day == [45] ]] && (( increment += 2 ))
date -d "+$increment days"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the -v option to `date` the advance date can be found.
There will be 16 days elapsed (includes 4 days of Saturdays and Sundays) 
unless the day is Thursday or Friday: in which case there will be 6 weekend days.

```
dn=$(date +'%w')  # 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday etc
days_inc=16
if [ $dn -gt 3 ];then
    days_inc=18
fi
date -v +${days_inc}d
```